# Unable to connect to Repository in Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse

I'm getting this error while i try to install new software through "Install New Software option" in Help menu.

"org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException"

Communication with repository at http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/ failed.

---

The Exception stack Trace is as follows:

---

I tried all the solutions which has been mentioned w.r.t this issue in previous discussions. its still not working.

I do not have proxy server. I'm using Windows 7 64 bit. My Eclipse Luna version is for the same.

Help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Try going to that URL in a web browser. What happens?

Comment: By following the link, it directs me to the download page with the following info."This URL is an Eclipse software repository; you must use it in Eclipse (see how)." and it suggests steps how to add this link in Eclipse -  install new Software dialog box.